# How can I change properties of FK in SQL Server database project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When working on an SQL Server database project in Visual Studio 2012, I'm encountering a strange issue. While I can easily modify the properties of a table, column or primary key, the Properties fields other than "(Name)" are disabled for foreign keys.

Why? Is there something I can do to be able to edit foreign keys directly through the Properties tab, or modifying them through the T-SQL pane is the only way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this cheat.

Open the corresponding table out of VS using a notepad and change the `table.sql` file permissions from `read only` to `editable`. After this, update the foreign key and save `table.sql` file.

Now, once again open the table in VS table designer and it should work. If you have the filed hooked to tfs, you can do dummy check-out and check-in for the file to ensure latest one is available on TFS too.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in SMSS/visual studio, you cannot edit the properties of a foreign key in a designer (like the properties window) because the designer usually needs to drop and recreate the table object.

if you use ALTER TABLE scripts however, you can drop and readd the FK constraint, with different properties.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: So why adding a command which allows to create a key, if it cannot be modified through the designer anyways?

Comment: I can't explain the exact engineering concepts behind MSs choices, but I would guess its because they can't tell exactly what attributes of the fk constraint have changed and how they impact the tables on either end, so they drop and recreate the objects in their entirety. I can only tell you what to do, not why it has to be done that way.

Comment: after thinking a bit about it, I don't think this is the reason. For Visual Studio, changing a property of a FK is nothing more than changing the corresponding text in the T-SQL pane. The database is not affected at this point, but only when publishing/deploying the project.